# Retrofit returns 404 respone code

Tags: android, retrofit2

ApiClient.java class -

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Interface -

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @POST("posts/1")
    Call<ModelClass> savePost();
}
```

In onCreate of activity -

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<ModelClass> call = apiService.savePost();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModelClass>call, Response<ModelClass> response) {

                Log.i(TAG,"response is "+response.body());
                Log.i(TAG,"response code is "+response.code());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ModelClass>call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.i(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

Dependencies which I included in Gradle -

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

why retrofit returns 404 response code.Is there any problem with the above code?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the internet permission?

Comment: Yes i already added.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? As in does the device have a working, active connection? Some times the Android OS cuts the connection (you are connected, but you can't send or receive data)

Comment: Yes the device is working properly n i have active internet connectivity.

Comment: @sanil 404 error code mean "you don't have this page inside your server" , if you open this url inside browser with same device , what happen?

Comment: 404 error code has nothing to do with retrofit. Its the response returned from the server. If i understand correctly you are making a post call, but you are not sending any data in post. Check on the service side, if any parameter is required in the body of the post.

Comment: @Deb but its a bad practice to show server error with 404 code..

Comment: @LakshayJain:404 status should not occur in the first place. But it might happen in-case the resource is not found for example some file is missing when you are trying to load a image. Its not a bad practice, but you need to handle it. BUT AGAIN I REPEAT , IT SHOULD NOT HAPPEN IN THE FIRST PLACE.

Comment: @Deb i am saying about using 404 error code on apis when parameters  is absent... It might confuse developers for api not exist.. Isn't it better to use a status code like 422 or 409

Comment: @sanil: I checked the url, it seems it does not support `POST` request, it is a `GET` request. It might be possible that on the service side they have explicitly specified the kind of request made to this url, since it is only reading the info and not saving it.

Comment: @LakshayJain: true, but then the api developer will have to write separate interceptors for such response. If its a dummy site, i doubt they will make that much effort.

Comment: Ok then accept the answer so this question is closed

Comment: Thanks Deb and LakshayJain.. I just changed my request type from post to GET and its working fine !

Answer (score 1):

Bro your code is fine problem is with api.
When i hit your api in post method on POSTMAN its showing 404 Not Found so please check your server

But its not showing the empty json object as body so maybe there are parameters missing and you are using 404 status for showing this which is a bad practice show 404 only when this api doesnt exist and use other error codes like 409,422 for this type of action so you are more clear about response

Answer (score 0):

What you should check if the endpoint is correct , or the url I had the same problem my BASE_URL was right but the endpoint not then I I was getting the 404 error.

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the postman for status server.
Usually there is response in the body but the status maybe still 404, so it will be errorbody not response.body.